# jQuery firing event when it shouldn't

Tags: jquery, events

I have a lot of jQuery click event handlers that I control by qualifying if it is active or not with an '**.active**' class. For example, if I do not want the event to fire I remove the class from the DOM element so that the event will not fire. I've used this technique alot, but I can't figure why it doesn't work for the handler below.  I've even set a breakpoint on the 1st line inside of the handler and typed in $(".tabs-nav a.active) at the console to check if a jQuery object exists and it returns a length of 0.

> $(".tabs-nav a.active") w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]length:
>   0prevObject: w.fn.init [document]**proto**: Object(0)

```
  // Tab Events - Product/Categories or Cart Tab
  $(".tabs-nav a.active").on("click", function(event) {

    var $el = $(this);
    var allowTabChange = function() {
      $(".tabs-nav li").removeClass("tab-active");
      $el.parent().addClass("tab-active");
      $(".tabs-stage > div").addClass('hide');
      // Show the correct tabs-stage using href target.
      $($el.attr("href")).removeClass('hide');
    } 

    event.preventDefault();    
    if ($(this).attr('href') === '#tab-1' ) {
      if ( ! verifyNoItemsEdited(true) ) {
         showTab('catalog');        
         allowTabChange();
      }
    }
    else {
      showTab('cart'); 
      allowTabChange(); 
      showCart();       
    }
  });
```

Comment: `$(document).on("click",".tabs-nav a.active", function(event) {` or ``$(".tabs-nav").on("click","a.active", function(event) {``

Comment: I will try it, but please explain the logic behind your answer.. It's not dynamically added html and I have other event handlers using the same technique.

Comment: Removing/Adding the class *makes it dynamic*.  The delegate event binding will make it evaluate the state of the element at the point that it gets the event.  So if the class is added/removed it will correctly process or not process.  If you direct bind on the element, and then change the class so that it doesn't match the selector any longer, it doesn't matter.  The binding is still on the element(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating snippets for the solution that **@Mohamed-Yousef** and **@Taplar** talked about.

Look at the example below, with no dynamic binding:

```js
$('.btn.active').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.bigGreenRectangle').toggleClass('toRed')
})

$('.btn.second').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.btn.first').toggleClass('active')

  if ($('.btn.first').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.isActive').text('ACTIVE: TRUE')
  } else {
    $('.isActive').text('ACTIVE: FALSE')
  }

})
```

```css
.bigGreenRectangle {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.bigGreenRectangle.toRed {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn first active">TOGGLE</button>
<div class="bigGreenRectangle">This changes color</div>
<button class="btn second">TOGGLE OTHER BUTTON</button><br />
<div class="isActive">ACTIVE: TRUE</div>
```

With dynamic binding:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn.active', function(e) {
  $('.bigGreenRectangle').toggleClass('toRed')
})

$('.btn.second').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.btn.first').toggleClass('active')

  if ($('.btn.first').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.isActive').text('ACTIVE: TRUE')
  } else {
    $('.isActive').text('ACTIVE: FALSE')
  }

})
```

```css
.bigGreenRectangle {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.bigGreenRectangle.toRed {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn first active">TOGGLE</button>
<div class="bigGreenRectangle">This changes color</div>
<button class="btn second">TOGGLE OTHER BUTTON</button><br />
<div class="isActive">ACTIVE: TRUE</div>
```

Comment: Superb demonstration!

Comment: I have other dynamic elements where I have used $(body) rather than $(document), does this make a difference?

Comment: @kruddock most of the time it doesn’t. Actually this dynamic binding should be on the element that’s the “closest non-dynamic” parent. **document** and **body** is for cases where you cannot tell the closest non-dynamic parent in advance - so it will scan the whole **document** (or **body**) to find it.